# How much food does a colonist eat each Sol?

Tags: surviving-mars

How much food does a colonist eat each Sol?

Also, I know colonists have flaws and disabilities than can modify the food. As a side question, do you know how much food does a **glutton** colonist eat each Sol?

Comment: Sadly hard to tell from the interface. The farm is showing 'food produced per 5 or 2 sols' and it's different depending on people working on it, soil quality and other factors. And the food produced is per, I dunno, sol?

Comment: I'm with 3 domes almost fulfilled right now and lot of stacks of food while having just one small farm working. I think they don't eat at all, lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](http://indiefaq.com/guides/201-surviving-mars.html), it is 0.2 food per sol (so 1 food per 5 sols), seems about right to me. Also you can click the resources tab and see how much food was produced and eaten in your colony last sol. If you play for International Mars Initiative, each colonist arrives with 10 units of food - good for lengthy 50 sols (almost a life time supply), hence your domes will most likely be surrounded by piles of food and you will not need to worry much.

Comment: Wow, 50 sols? That explains why I was able to totally pack a food storage unit in my first mystery as IMI...